# Dynamic SQL won't allow me to pass null variables to SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to write a Dynamic SQL query that will allow the end-user to opt-out of entering certain search criteria. In this example, I would like the end-user to be able to enter a value for `@GLAccountStart` without entering a value for `@GLAccountEnd` and have the "`IF ...`" statement where `@GLAccountStart IS NOT NULL and @GLAccountEnd IS NULL` execute correctly.

When I try to run this in SSRS, however, entering just the first value returns 0 rows (it should return 2), and entering values for both variables actually returns the correct number of rows.  Additionally, if I remove the `@GLAccountEnd` variable from my script entirely and just run it with the option to include `@GLAccountStart`, SSRS returns the correct number of rows with the proper input.

Is there a trick or something to implementing this?

```
USE [DataWarehouse]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[BrowseCODA]    Script Date: 6/27/2016 8:37:37 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BrowseCODA] 
@GLAccountStart int,
@GLAccountEnd int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQLQuery AS nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @ParameterDef AS nvarchar(2000)

SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT *
            FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[VDocDetails]
            WHERE Company+''-''+FullDocNumber IN 
                  (SELECT Company+''-''+FullDocNumber
                   FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[VDocDetails]
                   WHERE (1=1)'
IF (@GLAccountStart IS NOT NULL) AND (@GLAccountEnd IS NOT NULL)
    SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND (GLAccount >= @GLAccountStart) AND (GLAccount <= @GLAccountEnd)'
IF (@GLAccountStart IS NOT NULL) AND (@GLAccountEnd IS NULL)
    SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND (GLAccount = @GLAccountStart)'
SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ')'

SET @ParameterDef = 
'@GLAccountStart int,
 @GLAccountEnd int'

EXECUTE sp_Executesql @SQLQuery,
                      @ParameterDef,
                      @GLAccountStart,
                      @GLAccountEnd

IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO ErrorHandler
SET NOCOUNT OFF
RETURN(0)

ErrorHandler:
Return(@@ERROR)

GO
```

Comment: @Please post your parameter definition on SSRS. Is `GLAccountEnd` integer or text?

Comment: It's currently Text so that I can pass blank values to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess @GLAccountEnd is not getting a null value from SSRS. 
But, Why don't you try simple SQL?

```
   SELECT *
     FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[VDocDetails]
    where GLAccount between @GLAccountStart
                       AND  case @GLAccountEnd 
                            when '' then @GLAccountStart
                            else @GLAccountEnd end
```

or dynamic:

```
USE [DataWarehouse]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[BrowseCODA]    Script Date: 6/27/2016 8:37:37 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BrowseCODA] 
@GLAccountStart varchar,
@GLAccountEnd varchar
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQLQuery AS nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @ParameterDef AS nvarchar(2000)

SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT *
                   FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[VDocDetails]
                   WHERE (1=1)'
IF (@GLAccountStart <> '') AND (@GLAccountEnd <> '')
    SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND (GLAccount >= @GLAccountStart) AND (GLAccount <= @GLAccountEnd)'
IF (@GLAccountStart <> '') AND (@GLAccountEnd = '')
    SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND (GLAccount = @GLAccountStart)'

SET @ParameterDef = 
'@GLAccountStart int,
 @GLAccountEnd int'

EXECUTE sp_Executesql @SQLQuery,
                      @ParameterDef,
                      @GLAccountStart,
                      @GLAccountEnd

IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO ErrorHandler
SET NOCOUNT OFF
RETURN(0)

ErrorHandler:
Return(@@ERROR)

GO
```

Comment: The end-users would have to check "NULL" on SSRS if I did it that way, and they're not used to dealing with those kinds of issues. Basically, I'm trying to mimic an old computer program they're currently using.
1. If they enter the first value of a range but leave the second value blank, then it should only return documents where the search-value = first value.
2. If they enter both first and second, then search-value is between them.

Comment: so they are leaving the end-date empty?

Comment: Yes. Leaving the end empty SHOULD result in the rows returned being just where GLAccount = @GLAccountStart.

Comment: @DonFord I think my new answer will work in that case

Comment: I've been told to use Dynamic SQL specifically. :(

Comment: @DonFord Ok. let's try to change it.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS apparently takes the lack of input in the parameters to mean '' instead of NULL. When I changed the dynamic query to check against whether or not the values were equal to '', the code worked as-intended.

Comment: Yes, that's on the sp that I posted.